# Move a control to a floating location

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-2.0, controls

I want to move a `control` in `panel1` to the Red Line end from the following example:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 
        new PointF(10.7f, 20f), new PointF(50.5f, 20f));
}
```

Is that possible in .NET 2.0?

***Background***

I draw some paths using the floating (world) coordinates (PointF). Controls follow this paths.

Comment: I take it you are talking about WPF? You should tag your question as such to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Kragen: - done, no is not WFP.

Comment: perhaps your question is not as clear as it could be.  Do you want to *animate* the control *along* the path?  ie the user will see the control move along the red line?

Comment: @Ash: Yes. The control will move **with** the red line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is change it's location:

```
YourControl.Location = new Point(50, 20)
```

Comment: @serhio, your wording in the question didn't make it very clear.  It's courteous to first add a comment providing more information or to update the question.

Comment: The down vote is for an incorrect answer.  My answer was not incorrect based on your question.  You said "I want to move a control in panel1 to the Red Line end." The code above moves a control to the end of the line.  It's pretty clear from the comments on your post that others were sure what you were asking anyways.  Go to any other posts on here, do you see people down voting every answer that wasn't accepted?

Comment: sorry, man, but the question was about moving a control to a **floating** location. Everybody, I suppose, who developped the smallest WinForm app. know how to change a control location.

Comment: Thanks for starting to go to my other posts and down voting me.  Class act, dude!